# EF6 Code first model ForeignKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, foreign-keys

i got the an exception when i am trying to generate the database out of the followed model.

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'DataCenterBenchmark' on type
>   'Benchmark.Data.Context' is not valid. The foreign key
>   name 'BenchmarkId' was not found on the dependent type
>   'Benchmark.Data.Context'. The Name value should be a
>   comma separated list of foreign key property names.

```
[Table("Contexts")]
public class Context
{
    [Key]
    public Guid InternalId { get; set; }

    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Cluster { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Token { get; set; }
    [Required] public string IP { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Memo { get; set; }
    [Required] public string BenchType { get; set; }

    [Required] public int InstanceCount { get; set; }
    [Required] public int ThreadCount { get; set; }
    [Required] public int RequestCount { get; set; }

    [Required] public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [Required] public DateTime EditDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BenchmarkId")]
    public Benchmark RemoteBenchmark { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BenchmarkId")]
    public Benchmark DataCenterBenchmark { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BenchmarkId")]
    public Benchmark IISBenchmark { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BenchmarkId")]
    public Benchmark LocalBenchmark { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MachineTypeId")]
    [Required] public MachineType MachineType { get; set; }
}

[Table("Benchmarks")]
public class Benchmark
{
    [Key]
    public int BenchmarkId { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Result { get; set; }
    [Required] public DateTime Duration { get; set; }
}

[Table("MachineTypes")]
public class MachineType
{
    [Key]
    public int MachineTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BenchmarkContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Context> Contexts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Benchmark> Benchmarks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MachineType> MachineTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Tried to fix it with some tutorials - no victory..

Regards,
Marc

===== EDIT =====

After removing the [ForeignKey] flags i can't connect to my SQL Server (Error 26). I set no database as connection string so EF6 needs to create a localdb..?

Comment: Why multiple `[ForeignKey("BenchmarkId")]` on different navigation properties? What are you trying to achieve? What do you think the `[ForeignKey]` attribute is for?

Comment: I need 4 benchmark sets. Is there a better way to do?

Comment: Try to remove all of the `[ForeignKey]` attributes first. See what you got then re-describe your problem.

Comment: Thx haim, but now i have another error.. see in my edit :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A quick guide through ForeignKey property.**

When used on a key property (such as `int RemoteBenchmarkId`), its name should point to the navigation property (e.g. `Benchmark RemoteBenchmark`).
When used on a navigation property (this time `Benchmark RemoteBenchmark`) its name should point to the key property (such as `int RemoteBenchmarkId`).

The following code fragments are equivalent:

```
public class Context {
    //...other properties

    [ForeignKey("RemoteBenchmark")]
    public int RemoteBenchmarkId { get; set; }
    public Benchmark RemoteBenchmark { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Context {
    //...other properties

    public int RemoteBenchmarkId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RemoteBenchmarkId")]
    public Benchmark RemoteBenchmark { get; set; }
    }
```

With that in mind, what you probably want is 4 benchmarks, each having their own foreign key column (two benchmark properties using same key would point to the same instance, which is probably not what you want), like here:

```
public class Context {
    //...other properties

    [ForeignKey("RemoteBenchmark")]
    public int RemoteBenchmarkId { get; set; }
    public Benchmark RemoteBenchmark { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DataCenterBenchmark")]
    public int DataCenterBenchmarkId { get; set; }
    public Benchmark DataCenterBenchmark { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IISBenchmark")]
    public int IISBenchmarkId { get; set; }
    public Benchmark IISBenchmark { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocalBenchmark")]
    public int LocalBenchmarkId { get; set; }
    public Benchmark LocalBenchmark { get; set; }
    }
```

Don't forget to use `[Required]` annotation if context requires specific benchmarks!

Also, you might skip the `[ForeignKey]` annotations entirely allowing EF to infer columns itself (named `<navigation property name>_Id` by default, such as `RemoteBenchmark_Id`), but then you can't retrieve ids themselves without retrieving entire benchmark. Guess it all depends on specific cases; personally, I don't mind cluttering model with foreign key properties, since sometimes the keys themselves are enough.

(at least `[ForeignKey]` annotations *shouldn't* be necessary; if their lack causes errors, it might be another problem entirely...?)

Cheers~!

Answer (score 1):

You can *override* `OnModelCreating` method inside `BenchmarkContext` and to write the relation between tables like below.

**Notes:** You need to remove attributes `[ForeignKey("BenchmarkId")]`.

```
public class BenchmarkContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Context> Contexts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Benchmark> Benchmarks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MachineType> MachineTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Context>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.RemoteBenchmark)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(m => { m.MapKey("RemoteBenchmarkId"); });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Context>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.DataCenterBenchmark)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(m => { m.MapKey("DataCenterBenchmarkId"); });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Context>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.IISBenchmark)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(m => { m.MapKey("IISBenchmarkId"); });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Context>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.LocalBenchmark)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(m => { m.MapKey("LocalBenchmarkId"); });
    }
}
```